# Magento 2 payment methods based on billing address or shipping addrress

Tags: magento2, shipping, payment, billing

I have one small question, please suggest the correct answer.

In Magento 2 payment methods  are based on billing address or shipping address

Thanks in advance

Comment: You want to display payment methods based on address. Right?

Comment: no just I want to know default Magento 2 payment methods are based on shipping address or billing address by default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default in Magento 2 payment methods based on the billing address.

Here is example of that usage from the default payment method class:

to determine is payment method applicable for the customer's country the `Magento\Payment\Model\Checks\CanUseForCountry::isApplicable(MethodInterface $paymentMethod, Quote $quote)` method used, where the country comes from the `Magento\Payment\Model\Checks\CanUseForCountry\CountryProvider::getCountry($quote)` where billing address is prefered data source:

```
/**
 * Get payment country
 *
 * @param Quote $quote
 * @return int
 */
public function getCountry(Quote $quote)
{
    $address = $quote->getBillingAddress() ? : $quote->getShippingAddress();
    return (!empty($address) && !empty($address->getCountry()))
        ? $address->getCountry()
        : $this->directoryHelper->getDefaultCountry();
}
```

I think other parts of code in Magento use a same logic: billing address is preferred, but in case it is not set yet we can use shipping address.

Comment: But in code, it takes the shipping address for the country.